# JSX: How to make a word bold that can be found in a string

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have searched for the word 'red', the API returns this array

```
const resultArray = [{ type: "item", result: "red" },
 { type: "item", result: "redburn" },
 { type: "item", result: "red flame" },
 { type: "item", result: "red flame roses" },
 { type: "item", result: "imredde or not" },
];
```

and I can map over it and display the results...

```
{resultArray.map((item: any, index: number) => {
   return (
      <div key={`item-search-result-${index}`}>{item.result}</div>
   );
})}
```

How can I make the word 'red' bold, the HTML would be like....

```
<b>red<b/>
<b>red<b/>burn
<b>red<b/> flame
<b>red<b/> flame roses
im<b>red<b/>de or not
```

I have tried

```
{item.result.replace(/red/g, "<b>red<b/>")}
```

but the actual tags don't get rendered, but they are shown in the correct possition on the screen.

Is there a way in JSX to get the desired result without falling foul of the old `render unsafe HTML`?

Comment: I hade edited my question to detail what happens if is simply manipulate the string to have the correct tags, they don't get rendered, but instead displayed, so I think it is a jsx issue, I don't want to end up with using render unsafe HTML ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `red` keyword is appearing at beginning of every iteration string you can use `slice`, like this:

```
{resultArray.map((item: any, index: number) => {
   const str = item.result.slice(3);
   return (
      <div key={`item-search-result-${index}`}><b>red</b>{str}</div>
   );
})}
```

Using `split` it can be performed, like this

```
{
  resultArray.map((item: any, index: number) => {
    const strArr = item.result.split("red");

    return ( <div key={`item-search-result-${index}`}>{
        strArr.map((str, key) => {
          if (key === 0 && str === "") {
            return <b>red</b>;
          } else {
            if (key + 1 === strArr.length) {
              return <span>{str}</span>;
            } else {
              return <span>{str}<b>red</b></span>;
            }
          }
        })
      }</div>
    );
  })
}
```

Don't mind if the code is a bit distorted due to the use of `tidy`.

Comment: I like it, this deals with 90% of the search results, but I just checked and there are a few that have the word positioned not at the start

Comment: then you can use `split` with the keyword `red`, it will give you an array which you can iterate with the combination of `<b>red</b>` in the middle of simple strings.

Comment: and you think the tags will render?

Comment: yes they will as b tag is not block-level, so you can place as many b tags inside a div tag

Comment: I can write example code using split also, if you want

Comment: if you could i cant imagine it, split will give an array of strings, then you loop over that array inserting <b> tags?

Comment: I have edited my answer for you using `split` in below code

Comment: Genius! I love it, it works perfectly, I learnt a lot from this, thank you so much